# Change position of label in a custom UITableViewCell connected with xib file when orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i have a custom UITableviewCell xib, connected with my uitableview, and i'll do it in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    cell = myCell;
    self.myCell = nil;
}

[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
```

then when change the orientation of the device, i want change the position of some element in my custom UITableViewCell so in this method:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {

    CGRect myframe = CGRectMake(600, self.arrowLabel.frame.origin.y, self.arrowLabel.frame.size.width, self.arrowLabel.frame.size.height);
        self.arrowLabel.frame = myframe;
} else {

    CGRect myframe = CGRectMake(400, self.arrowLabel.frame.origin.y, self.arrowLabel.frame.size.width, self.arrowLabel.frame.size.height);
        self.arrowLabel.frame = myframe;
}
}
```

i change the frame.origin.y and frame.origin.y of my arrowLabel connected with my UITableViewCell xib but change only the position of the last row of the tableview, the other label in the other row remain in the same position, so my question is how i can reload the table view?...i have also tried with [self.tableview reloadData];...but don't work...any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try putting the frame change codes in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Basically in that method you have something like:

```
if (portrait) {
    // use portrait frames
} else {
    // use landscape frames
}
```

And then in your `willRotate` method you can call `[tableView reloadData]`.

**Edit:**

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells]) {

    if (portrait) {
        CGRect myframe = CGRectMake(600, cell.arrowLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.arrowLabel.frame.size.width, cell.arrowLabel.frame.size.height);
        cell.arrowLabel.frame = myframe;
    } else {
        CGRect myframe = CGRectMake(400, cell.arrowLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.arrowLabel.frame.size.width, cell.arrowLabel.frame.size.height);
        cell.arrowLabel.frame = myframe;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What change?...i already say that i also tried with reloadData that call the cellrowforindexpath method...

Comment: No, I mean in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, specify the frame you want to use based on orientation. Then in your `willRotate`, you can call `reloadData`.

Comment: Maybe wrap what you did in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` with `for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells])`? Hopefully this will apply to all cells.

Comment: i have also subclassed the UITableViewCell, because i use the xib file and (UITableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells]) don't give me the IBOutlet connected to the cell, i have to use the Tag but i write that it's not a better choice, so i subclassed it and then i use (MyCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells])...thanks for the hint!

Comment: In my case i am expanding(increasing the cell height) the custom cell with the help of a button now when we reload the tableview in will rotate method all the cells will be redrawn right which will loss the state of the expanded cell right??? :(